# How to prevent text highlighting when clicking on Quasar Select

Tags: javascript, quasar-framework, quasar

The default Quasar Select behaviour when there is text in the input box and the select is focussed is to highlight the text. How can I prevent this and just have the text cursor at the end of the text or where the cursor was clicked?
The Quasar docs with the default behaviour can be found here https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#example--text-autocomplete

Below is a video of the default behaviour when I click the q-select from being blurred, I want to be able to click on the select and have a cursor at the point that I clicked rather than the text highlighting as that then requires two clicks to continue typing
[GIF of default behaviour of q-select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vti2D.gif)

Comment: There are `color` and `label-color` props. Or are you talking about the text in the options list?

Comment: I've updated my question with a GIF for clarity.

Comment: I didn't understand why, but there is no text highlighting in the "basic filtering" example. Perhaps this option will work for you.

Comment: That wont work, basic filtering doesn't save text when the field is blurred